# Jsoup select elements after first element

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

i want to parse a html table with jsoup.

part of the html page i want to parse:

```
<tr>
    <td class="dkHeading">A1</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A2</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A3</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A4</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A5</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A6</td>
    <td class="dkHeading">A7</td>
</tr>
<tr id="RContents">
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B1</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B2</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B3</td>
    <td class="dkTextLeft">B4</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B5</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B6</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">B7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C1</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C2</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C3</td>
    <td class="dkTextLeft">C4</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C5</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C6</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">C7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D1</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D2</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D3</td>
    <td class="dkTextLeft">D4</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D5</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D6</td>
    <td class="dkTextCenter">D7</td>
  </tr>
```

how can i select all "tr" elements after (and including) that tr with id "RContents"?
i tried `doc.select("tr[id=RContents] > tr");` but that did't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the next siblings selector ~:

```
doc.select("tr[id=RContents] ~ tr");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select `tr Elements`, then `loop` through them. since the elements are in order you can try something like this:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.parse("YOURHTML");

    Elements elements = document.select("tr");

    boolean start=false;
    for(Element e : elements){
        if(e.hasAttr("id") && e.attr("id").equals("RContents"))){   
            start=true;
        }

        if(start){
         //all tr elements including id=RContents and after
        }
    }
```